# installation requirement about wordpress and article directory

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress and article directory , what I would like to do is just want to have a platform to upload file for user reading , I know article directory can do that .

My question is 
1) wordpress is must install , can article directory works alone ?
2) I have to setup mysql server ?
3) would advise the simple installation guide for reference

thanks